# How to rewrite a NOT IN subquery as join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

Let's assume that the following tables in MySQL describe documents contained in folders.

```
mysql> select * from folder;
+----+----------------+
| ID | PATH           |
+----+----------------+
|  1 | matches/1      |
|  2 | matches/2      |
|  3 | shared/3       |
|  4 | no/match/4     |
|  5 | unreferenced/5 |
+----+----------------+


mysql> select * from DOC;
+----+------+------------+
| ID | F_ID | DATE       |
+----+------+------------+
|  1 |    1 | 2000-01-01 |
|  2 |    2 | 2000-01-02 |
|  3 |    2 | 2000-01-03 |
|  4 |    3 | 2000-01-04 |
|  5 |    3 | 2000-01-05 |
|  6 |    3 | 2000-01-06 |
|  7 |    4 | 2000-01-07 |
|  8 |    4 | 2000-01-08 |
|  9 |    4 | 2000-01-09 |
| 10 |    4 | 2000-01-10 |
+----+------+------------+
```

The columns ID are the primary keys and the column F_ID of table DOC is a not-null foreign key that references the primary key of table FOLDER. By using the 'DATE' of documents in the where clause, I would like to find which folders contain only the selected documents. For documents earlier than 2000-01-05, this could be written as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT d1.F_ID 
FROM DOC d1 
WHERE d1.DATE < '2000-01-05' 
AND d1.F_ID NOT IN (
    SELECT d2.F_ID 
    FROM DOC d2 WHERE NOT (d2.DATE < '2000-01-05')
);
```

and it correctly returns '1' and '2'. By reading 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/rewriting-subqueries.html
the performance for big tables could be improved if the subquery is replaced with a join. I already found questions related to NOT IN and JOINS but not exactly what I was looking for. So, any ideas of how this could be written with joins ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select distinct d1.F_ID
from DOC d1
left outer join (
    select F_ID
    from DOC 
    where date >= '2000-01-05'
) d2 on d1.F_ID = d2.F_ID
where d1.date < '2000-01-05' 
    and d2.F_ID is null
```

Comment: Correct and ultra fast response ! Although I did not ask, I guess I can not avoid repeating the '2000-01-05'.

Comment: Will a subquery join perform better than a subquery on `WHERE`?

Answer (score 11):

The general answer is:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id not in (select id from s)
```

Can be rewritten as:

```
select t.*
from t left outer join
     (select distinct id from s) s
     on t.id = s.id
where s.id is null
```

I think you can apply this to your situation.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, that you want to find the F_IDs representing folders which only contains documents from before '2000-01-05', then simply

```
SELECT F_ID 
FROM DOC 
GROUP BY F_ID 
HAVING MAX(DATE) < '2000-01-05'
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I was asking for and this is indeed a simpler and correct query. But, reality is that the DOC table has more columns and the where clause will be programmatically generated. It seems to me easier to dynamically add 'where' clauses rather than 'having' but I will check the performance with big tables and give it a try. Thanks !

Comment: Your welcome, I would give this a read though as well http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html. Also, I don't know how your schema looks, besides the subset you have exposed here. But I tend to go by the rule of thumb that "if I need a sub-query, I should revisit my data model". In other words, maybe normalizing your model might make things cleaner/easier to implement :)

Answer (score 0):

Sample Table and Insert Statements

```
CREATE TABLE `tleft` (
  `id` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `tright` (
  `id` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `t_left_id` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8



INSERT INTO `tleft` (`id`, `name`)
VALUES
    (1, 'henry'),
    (2, 'steve'),
    (3, 'jeff'),
    (4, 'richards'),
    (5, 'elon');



INSERT INTO `tright` (`id`, `t_left_id`, `description`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 'sample'),
    (2, 2, 'sample');
```

**Left Join :** `SELECT l.id,l.name FROM tleft l LEFT JOIN tright r ON l.id = r.t_left_id ;`

Returns Id : 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

**Right Join :** `SELECT l.id,l.name FROM tleft l RIGHT JOIN tright r ON l.id = r.t_left_id ;`

Returns Id : 1,2

**Subquery Not in tright :** `select id from tleft where id not in ( select t_left_id from tright);`

Returns Id : 3,4,5

**Equivalent Join For above subquery :**

```
SELECT l.id,l.name FROM tleft l LEFT JOIN tright r ON l.id = r.t_left_id WHERE r.t_left_id IS NULL;
```

`AND` clause will be applied during the JOIN and `WHERE` clause will be applied after the JOIN .

**Example :** `SELECT l.id,l.name FROM tleft l LEFT JOIN tright r ON l.id = r.t_left_id AND r.description ='hello' WHERE r.t_left_id IS NULL ;`

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for acting on [mcve]. Especially the table-format initializations. It would be nicer if your queries were properly indented code blocks. PS This question is poor & (obviously) a duplicate (even when posted) & should be closed. Also it's not clear what this answer adds to other answers or answers on duplicates, and it doesn't have much specific to the question, so (per the downvote arrow mouseover text) it's not very "useful". Please see [ask] & [answer].